# Check if date have a specific format

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to check if a date have a format to save it or no, I use the function  strptime() :

```
if (!strptime($contact[14], '%Y') && isset($contact[14]) && $contact[14] != ""){
      $date_naissance =  $contact[14];
      dsm("BON FORMAT : ".$contact[14]);
    } else {
      $date_naissance = null;
      dsm("MAUVAIS FORMAT : ".$contact[14]);
    }
```

The problem is that the format seems not working, i need to validate all date with format year (like this : 2010, 2020, ..) but they are not validate, I don't understand why, in the php date documentation the Y is for a 4 digit year representation.

Anyone have an idea ?

Edit : with CreateFromFormat :

```
if(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', $contact[22])){
      dsm("Bon format : ".$contact[22]);
      $date_derniere_inscription = strtotime($contact[22]);
    } else {
      $date_derniere_inscription = null;
    }
```

But the date with only two digits and even the date with 0 value are validated too.

The 'Y' format seems doesn't work, with all the values (for example, 2012 but also 96 or 0) it create a date, with a 0 value it create '0000-07-11 10:38:45.000000' .. what is wrong with this format ?

Comment: What is the value in `$contact[22]`?

Comment: I have multiple values here is the output: Bon format : 0
Bon format : 1996
Bon format : 96, as you can see all the values are validated

Comment: And another problem, with for example the 2012 value, the output is  2012-07-11 10:33:47.000000, I need 2012-01-01 00:00:0000

Answer (score 2):

[createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) can help in this case. It will return false if given date string will not in given format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '11-Jan-2018');

if ($date) {
    echo 'In format';
} else {
    echo 'Not in format';
}
```

For resetting all fields (Month, day, Minutes, seconds) except year, you can use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y|', '2012');
```

And output will be: `2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000`. Can be converted to any format using [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function.

Comment: Thanks this work but I have someting strange, the format I use in createFromFormat is 'Y' but the values with only two digits are validated too, how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression to do this.

```
/(\d{4})/
```

Sample code:

```
<?php
$pattern = "/(\d{4})/";
$year = "2015";
if(preg_match($pattern, $year)){
    echo "Format correct!";
} else{
    echo "Format incorrect!";
}
?>
```

For more information on regex, check the 
[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and the 
[REGEX Builder & Tester](https://regexr.com/3s92c)